# Conditional probability symbols

Tags: probability

What does the upside-down U mean between stocks and fixed income? And what does the line mean in between fixed income and stocks? Thanks! [image]

Comment: it means intersection, i.e. $A \cap B$ means both $A$ and $B$ happen for events $A,B$.

Comment: What's the line then?

Comment: The symbol for denoting a conditional probability.  $P(A\mid B)$ is the probability of event $A$ occurring **given that** we have knowledge that $B$ has occurred.  And *by definition* we have $P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

Comment: Oh..... Thanks!!